# TabHost with tabs inside scrollviews - scrolling works only for one tab

Tags: android, android-layout

I have TabHost with three tabs. One of these tabs contains ListActivity. I want all three tabs to be scrollable. At first I put FrameLayout(tabcontent) inside ScrollView but I can't put ListActivity inside ScrollView so I added ScrollView for each tab(except the third one with ListActivity). Now scrolling works only for second tab. When I am trying to scroll first one scrollbar is moving but content isn't. It looks like only ScrollView containing second tab has focus even when I am on first tab.

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/black">

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <!-- TAB1 -->
                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab1Layout"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:padding="5dp">
                        <TextView
                            anddroid:id="@+id/textview11"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        <TextView
                            anddroid:id="@+id/textview12"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        <TextView
                            anddroid:id="@+id/textview13"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        <TextView
                            anddroid:id="@+id/textview14"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                            <!-- FEW MORE TEXTVIEWS -->
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>
                <!-- TAB 2 -->
                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab2Layout"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:padding="5dp">
                        <TextView
                            anddroid:id="@+id/textview21"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        <TextView
                            anddroid:id="@+id/textview22"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        <TextView
                            anddroid:id="@+id/textview23"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        <TextView
                            anddroid:id="@+id/textview24"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                            <!-- FEW MORE TEXTVIEWS -->
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>
                <!-- TAB3 -->
                <!-- ListActivity here -->
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not like that

You can not take a separate Scrollview or any view for tab
The TabWidget it self contains Tabs and for content You can use FramLayout 
and this FramLayout will contains your Activity which you want to open by clicking Tab.